# Php login not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, login-script

So I've been trying to pull up something we did in class last night but I just can't figure it out somehow. It's not like a real login, I'm only trying to sort of compare the email and pass that the input gets with the ones stored in the database but I keep getting access denied.

So this is the form:

```
<form id="login_form" method="POST" action="index.php?pagina=login">

                                <input title="Ingrese su email" id="login_email" class="_click_clean _round" type="text" name="email" value="Email ..." />
                                <input title="Ingrese su clave" id="login_pass"  class="_click_clean _round" type="password" name="pass" value="" />
                                <input class="boton_login _round" id="login_submit" type="submit" value="Ingresar" />

                            </form>
```

This is what I have in my login.php:

```
<?php $resultado=login($_POST["email"], $_POST["pass"]);?>

    <div id="cuerpo" style="height:auto;">



        <div id="izquierda">
                <?php
            require "templates/menues/menu.php";
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="principal">
                        <?php 

                        $pass=SHA1($_POST["pass"]);
                        if ($resultado["email"]==$_POST["email"] && $resultado["pass"]==$pass){

                        echo "<h1>Login Exsitoso!</h1>";
                        echo "<p>bienvenido</p>". $resultado["email"];
                        }
                         echo "acceso denegado";

                                ?>

        </div>

    </div>
```

This is the function i'm using:

```
  <?php

function login($email, $pass){
$pass=  sha1($pass);
$sql="SELECT FROM usuarios email, pass WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'";
$resultado= query($sql);

if(!sizeof($resultado)){
    return FALSE;
 }
 return $resultado[0];
}

?>
```

and this is what I have in a db.inc.php file:

```
function bufferedQuery($sql){
$resultado= query($sql);
$datos= Array();
while($fila= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    $datos[]=$fila;
}
return $datos;
}
```

all I keep getting is "acceso denegado" which is what I told it to say in case the email and pass didn't match with db. Hope you can help, thanks!

Comment: `SELECT email, pass from usuarios`

Comment: $sql="SELECT FROM usuarios email, pass WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'"; seems wrong, TRY $sql="SELECT email, pass FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'"; BUT!!!! please use PDO otherwise SQL injection risk

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your login function has a bug in the SQL which looks up the given email address and password. On line 2 of that function you wrote:

```
$sql="SELECT FROM usuarios email, pass WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'";
```

It should instead be:

```
$sql="SELECT email, pass FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'";
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I can't believe I didn't see that. Nontheless, now that I try to run it, it says that _Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array ... on line 17_  . I checked and on that line all I have is **$pass= sha1($_POST["pass"]);                            if($resultado["email"]==$_POST["email"] && resultado["pass"]==$pass)
                              {echo "<H1>Bienvenido</H1>";
                               echo "<p>".$resultado["email"].</p>";
                              }
                              echo "acceso denegado";**
Any suggestions?

Comment: The error message is fairly self-explanatory. The `$resultado` variable is of type mysqli_result (an object) and you are trying to use array notation. In other words `$resultado['pass']` is wrong.